# How to make the div data not to wrap on ASP.NET View page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, css-float

I have two DIV tags in my Products.aspx view page as below.

When we minimise/resize the application window, the payLoad div section is wrapping to down. Right hand side data(payLoad div) getting display below the left hand side data. I don't want to wrap the data.

How to make data NOT to wrap to bottom?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="navigation" style="float: left; width: 250px; margin-right: 15px;"><% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/NavTree.ascx"); %></div>
<div id="payload" nowrap  style="float: left; width: 600px; "><% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/Payload.ascx"); %></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using floats, you can do this instead:

```
<div id="columns">
  <div id="navigation">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/NavTree.ascx"); %>
  </div>
  <div id="payload">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/Payload.ascx"); %>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
#columns {
    position: relative;
}

#navigation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
}

#payload {
    margin-left: 265px;
}
```

Note that this will cause problems if the navigation div is taller than the content, since the navigation div's height does not change the height of its container.  To work around this, you could add a `min-height` CSS property to `#columns`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a container around the whole thing?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div style="width:865px;">
<div id="navigation" style="float: left; width: 250px; margin-right: 15px;"><% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/NavTree.ascx"); %></div>
<div id="payload" nowrap  style="float: left; width: 600px; "><% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/Payload.ascx"); %></div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```